# How to update python from 2.7.3 to 2.7.4 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, updates, python

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 with python 2.7.3 installed. How can I update the version of python to 2.7.4?

```
apt-get install python2.7
```

does not install anything new

```
apt-get update python2.7
```

does not work as it does not accept arguments

```
apt-get upgrade python2.7
```

Installed version 2.7.3, but not change to version 2.7.4.

So: How to install the version 2.7.4 of python on Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: what does `python -v` says ?

Comment: If you mean `python -V` it says 2.7.3. As explained in my question.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?  Body of question says 10.04 which makes this **off topic** unless its the Server version. However tag says 12.04.  Which is it?

Comment: **Why** would you want 2.7.4? Fixes are being backported to 2.7.3 in 12.04 instead of upgrade to a newer release for the same reason as *any other package*: [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](http://askubuntu.com/q/151283/88802)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The versions of `python2.7` available for each supported version of Ubuntu are [listed on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7). Only 2.7.3 is packaged on Ubuntu 12.04. If you want to use 2.7.4, there are several options:

- Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10, and then to 13.04, which includes 2.7.4.
- Request a backport of the 2.7.4 package to 12.04.
- Backport it yourself, either locally, or in your own PPA.
- If there is a specific fix you need, request it be backported to 2.7.3 on 12.04.
- Build and install from source (not really recommended though).

Comment: Why is building it from source not recommended?  Is requesting a backport realistic or shouting at the wind?